# How can I pass a cloud-config script for post-installation configuration in SoftLayer?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

My question has 2 parts:

1. Is there *any way* at all to pass a cloud-config formatted script to a machine? I do not mean a post installation script in Python, or in Bash etc. I want it to be cloud-config formatted (e.g. `#cloud-config`).
2. If there is a way to use the REST API to pass this script as a parameter, then the `postInstallScriptUri` parameter does not suit my case. All the examples that I've found are examples of remotely fetched scripts, that are not in cloud-config format.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the cloud config formatted data in "metadata"(userData), but I think it will only run during a core os provision. I've never tested the provisions with cloud-init but It should work, core os has to use it.

Here a REST API example to specify "metadata(userData)":

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject
```

Payload:

```
 {  
       "parameters":[  
          {  
             "hostname":"hostnameTest",
             "domain":"softlayer.com",
             "maxMemory":2048,
             "startCpus":1,
             "hourlyBillingFlag":false,
             "localDiskFlag":false,
             "operatingSystemReferenceCode":"UBUNTU_LATEST",
             "datacenter":{  
                "name":"dal05"
             },
             "userData":[  
                {  
                   "value":"someValue"
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
```

References:

- [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject)